# A function is zeroed the same amount of times

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ and let $\beta \in \Bbb{R}$

Say, we define $g_\beta(x) = f(x-\beta)$

Why is that $f$ is zeroed a finite number of times means that $g_\beta$ is zeroed the same amount of times $f$ is?

Thanks.

Comment: With $x'=x+\beta$, $g_\beta(x')=0\iff f(x)=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust IMHO you should post it as an answer, not a comment! You show for each zero of $f$ there exist exactly one corresponding zero of $g$, and vice versa.

Comment: @CiaPan: I know, but this is so trivial that I feel ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graphs . . .

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, let $b \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $g(x) = f(x-b)$. Then the graph of $g$ is the same as the graph of $f$ except shifted horizontally$\,-\,$right by $|b|$, or left by $|b|$, according as $b>0$ or $b<0$. But a horinsontal shift just shifts the zeros, as represented by the $x$-intercepts, hence the shift yields a one-to-one correspondence between the zeros of $f$ and the zeros of $g$.